# How to parse the gmail messages.get() batch response in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, api, gmail-api

I have batched and executed my request using the following code:

```
batch = BatchHttpRequest()
for msg_id in message_ids:
    batch.add(service.users().messages().get(userId = 'me', id = msg_id['id']), callback = mycallbackfunc)
batch.execute()
```

How can I access the responses for each of the requests? I have looked through the documentation but there is no public method to get the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You access the response of each request in the `callback` function, which is called `mycallbackfunc` in your example:

```
def process_message(request_id, response, exception):
  if exception is not None:
    # Do something with the exception
    pass
  else:
    # Do something with the response
    pass

batch = BatchHttpRequest()
for msg_id in message_ids:
    batch.add(service.users().messages().get(userId = 'me', id = msg_id['id']), callback=process_message)
batch.execute()
```